# Flutter account security using multiple auth verification

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, e-commerce

i want to make an application that check if the user is a real user. i want to create an double/multiple auth like some app did.

something like e-commerce app, the user create an account using login signup with firebase on flutter. when the user already sign in how can i check/ask user to did more verification something like 1 user account will need phone number and email verification to be able did something like upload a product or buying a product

i already make the user can be login using email, google sign in, an anonymus login

and once again how can i check if user is anonymus?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [isAnonymous](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#isanonymous) property of the user to know if the user is an anonymous user or a real authenticated user.

From your question it seems you want to re-authenticate the user before buying or uploading a product. For that you can use any of the following methods.

- [reauthenticateWithCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#reauthenticatewithcredential)
- [reauthenticateWithPhoneNumber](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#reauthenticatewithphonenumber)
- [reauthenticateWithRedirect](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#reauthenticatewithredirect)
- [reauthenticateWithPopup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#reauthenticatewithpopup)

Comment: ah so for an account like if i register using email. i can did reauth using phonenumber and email too?

Comment: You can use your phone number if you have linked your phone before. [You can link multiple auth providers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) to an account.

Comment: aha, letme try it first and check it, thank you :)

Comment: @Royalindo have you checked it?

Comment: still not yet. need some redesign first, but letme up vote it first

Comment: look like cant be used

Comment: Can you explain in detail what you have tried and what can not be used?

Comment: i got signup screen and login screen that can be register without using authentication. and when i trying to re-auth isnt it only for changing password? i havent did it yet. but from what i read look like that. want to continue at chat?

Comment: No, reauth is not only for password change. You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user). I would suggest you implement it and check.